# Get bounds of filters applied to Flash Sprite within Sprite

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, sprite, filter

I have a Flash library with Sprite symbols composed of other sprites with design-time applied filters.  I'm embedding those symbols into a Flex application like so:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            [Embed(source="Resources.swf", symbol="SquareContainer")]
            private var squareContainer_class:Class;

            private function log(msg:String):void {
                    output.text = output.text + "\n" + msg;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:VBox horizontalAlign="center" width="100%" height="100%" >
        <mx:Image id="squareContainer" source="{squareContainer_class}"/>
        <mx:Button click="log(squareContainer.width + ', ' + squareContainer.height);"/>
        <mx:TextArea id="output" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

In this example, the SquareContainer symbol is 100px wide by 100px height; however it contains a child sprite with a glow and blur filter, that cause the sprite to appear to be significantly larger than 100x100.  Since I cannot know for certain the composition of the container, I cannot use BitmapData.generateFilterRect() to get at the filters applied to nested sprites.

How can I get the size of the sprite plus its filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh sweet success! (and thanks for the tips)  A friend helped solve the problem with a nice recursive function to handle the filters which may exist on nested sprites:

```
private function getDisplayObjectRectangle(container:DisplayObjectContainer, processFilters:Boolean):Rectangle {
    var final_rectangle:Rectangle = processDisplayObjectContainer(container, processFilters);

    // translate to local
    var local_point:Point = container.globalToLocal(new Point(final_rectangle.x, final_rectangle.y));
    final_rectangle = new Rectangle(local_point.x, local_point.y, final_rectangle.width, final_rectangle.height);       

    return final_rectangle;
}

private function processDisplayObjectContainer(container:DisplayObjectContainer, processFilters:Boolean):Rectangle {
    var result_rectangle:Rectangle = null;

    // Process if container exists
    if (container != null) {
        var index:int = 0;
        var displayObject:DisplayObject;

        // Process each child DisplayObject
        for(var childIndex:int = 0; childIndex < container.numChildren; childIndex++){
            displayObject = container.getChildAt(childIndex);

            //If we are recursing all children, we also get the rectangle of children within these children.
            if (displayObject is DisplayObjectContainer) {

                // Let's drill into the structure till we find the deepest DisplayObject
                var displayObject_rectangle:Rectangle = processDisplayObjectContainer(displayObject as DisplayObjectContainer, processFilters);

                // Now, stepping out, uniting the result creates a rectangle that surrounds siblings
                if (result_rectangle == null) { 
                    result_rectangle = displayObject_rectangle.clone(); 
                } else {
                    result_rectangle = result_rectangle.union(displayObject_rectangle);
                }                       
            }                       
        }

        // Get bounds of current container, at this point we're stepping out of the nested DisplayObjects
        var container_rectangle:Rectangle = container.getBounds(container.stage);

        if (result_rectangle == null) { 
            result_rectangle = container_rectangle.clone(); 
        } else {
            result_rectangle = result_rectangle.union(container_rectangle);
        }


        // Include all filters if requested and they exist
        if ((processFilters == true) && (container.filters.length > 0)) {
            var filterGenerater_rectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,result_rectangle.width, result_rectangle.height);
            var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(result_rectangle.width, result_rectangle.height, true, 0x00000000);

            var filter_minimumX:Number = 0;
            var filter_minimumY:Number = 0;

            var filtersLength:int = container.filters.length;
            for (var filtersIndex:int = 0; filtersIndex < filtersLength; filtersIndex++) {                      
                var filter:BitmapFilter = container.filters[filtersIndex];

                var filter_rectangle:Rectangle = bmd.generateFilterRect(filterGenerater_rectangle, filter);

                filter_minimumX = filter_minimumX + filter_rectangle.x;
                filter_minimumY = filter_minimumY + filter_rectangle.y;

                filterGenerater_rectangle = filter_rectangle.clone();
                filterGenerater_rectangle.x = 0;
                filterGenerater_rectangle.y = 0;

                bmd = new BitmapData(filterGenerater_rectangle.width, filterGenerater_rectangle.height, true, 0x00000000);                      
            }

            // Reposition filter_rectangle back to global coordinates
            filter_rectangle.x = result_rectangle.x + filter_minimumX;
            filter_rectangle.y = result_rectangle.y + filter_minimumY;

            result_rectangle = filter_rectangle.clone();
        }               
    } else {
        throw new Error("No displayobject was passed as an argument");
    }

    return result_rectangle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach: just draw the entire object into `BitmapData` and then calculate the bounds of the non-transparent area of the bitmap. This approach might be more performant, especially on complex objects.

```
package lup.utils
{
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class BoundsHelper
    {
        private var _hBmd:BitmapData;
        private var _hBmdRect:Rectangle;
        private var _hMtr:Matrix;
        private var _hPoint:Point;

        private var _xMin:Number;
        private var _xMax:Number;
        private var _yMin:Number;
        private var _yMax:Number;

        /**
         * Specify maxFilteredObjWidth and maxFilteredObjHeight to match the maximum possible size
         * of a filtered object. Performance of the helper is inversely proportional to the product
         * of these values.
         *
         * @param maxFilteredObjWidth Maximum width of a filtered object.
         * @param maxFilteredObjHeight Maximum height of a filtered object.
         */
        public function BoundsHelper(maxFilteredObjWidth:Number = 500, maxFilteredObjHeight:Number = 500) {
            _hMtr = new Matrix();
            _hPoint = new Point();
            _hBmd = new BitmapData(maxFilteredObjWidth, maxFilteredObjHeight, true, 0);
            _hBmdRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, maxFilteredObjWidth, maxFilteredObjHeight);
        }

        /**
         * Calculates the boundary rectangle of an object relative to the given coordinate space.
         *
         * @param obj The object which bounds are to be determined.
         *
         * @param space The coordinate space relative to which the bounds should be represented.
         *        If you pass null or the object itself, then the bounds will be represented
         *        relative to the (untransformed) object.
         *
         * @param dst Destination rectangle to store the result in. If you pass null,
         *        new rectangle will be created and returned. Otherwise, the passed
         *        rectangle will be updated and returned.
         */
        public function getRealBounds(obj:DisplayObject, space:DisplayObject = null, dst:Rectangle = null):Rectangle {
            var tx:Number = (_hBmdRect.width  - obj.width ) / 2,
                ty:Number = (_hBmdRect.height - obj.height) / 2;

            // get transformation matrix that translates the object to the center of the bitmap
            _hMtr.identity();
            _hMtr.translate(tx, ty);

            // clear the bitmap so it will contain only pixels with zero alpha channel
            _hBmd.fillRect(_hBmdRect, 0);
            // draw the object; it will be drawn untransformed, except for translation
            // caused by _hMtr matrix
            _hBmd.draw(obj, _hMtr);

            // get the area which encloses all pixels with nonzero alpha channel (i.e. our object)
            var bnd:Rectangle = dst ? dst : new Rectangle(),
                selfBnd:Rectangle = _hBmd.getColorBoundsRect(0xFF000000, 0x00000000, false);

            // transform the area to eliminate the effect of _hMtr transformation; now we've obtained
            // the bounds of the object in its own coord. system (self bounds)
            selfBnd.offset(-tx, -ty);

            if (space && space !== obj) { // the dst coord space is different from the object's one
                // so we need to obtain transformation matrix from the object's coord space to the dst one
                var mObjToSpace:Matrix;

                if (space === obj.parent) {
                    // optimization
                    mObjToSpace = obj.transform.matrix;
                } else if (space == obj.stage) {
                    // optimization
                    mObjToSpace = obj.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
                } else {
                    // general case
                    var mStageToSpace:Matrix = space.transform.concatenatedMatrix; // space -> stage
                        mStageToSpace.invert();                                    // stage -> space
                    mObjToSpace = obj.transform.concatenatedMatrix;                // obj -> stage
                    mObjToSpace.concat(mStageToSpace);                             // obj -> space
                }

                // now we transform all four vertices of the boundary rectangle to the target space
                // and determine the bounds of this transformed shape

                _xMin =  Number.MAX_VALUE;
                _xMax = -Number.MAX_VALUE;
                _yMin =  Number.MAX_VALUE;
                _yMax = -Number.MAX_VALUE;

                expandBounds(mObjToSpace.transformPoint(getPoint(selfBnd.x, selfBnd.y)));
                expandBounds(mObjToSpace.transformPoint(getPoint(selfBnd.right, selfBnd.y)));
                expandBounds(mObjToSpace.transformPoint(getPoint(selfBnd.x, selfBnd.bottom)));
                expandBounds(mObjToSpace.transformPoint(getPoint(selfBnd.right, selfBnd.bottom)));

                bnd.x = _xMin;
                bnd.y = _yMin;
                bnd.width = _xMax - _xMin;
                bnd.height = _yMax - _yMin;
            } else {
                // the dst coord space is the object's one, so we simply return the self bounds
                bnd.x = selfBnd.x;
                bnd.y = selfBnd.y;
                bnd.width = selfBnd.width;
                bnd.height = selfBnd.height;
            }

            return bnd;
        }

        private function getPoint(x:Number, y:Number):Point {
            _hPoint.x = x;
            _hPoint.y = y;
            return _hPoint;
        }

        private function expandBounds(p:Point):void {
            if (p.x < _xMin) {
                _xMin = p.x;
            }
            if (p.x > _xMax) {
                _xMax = p.x;
            }
            if (p.y < _yMin) {
                _yMin = p.y;
            }
            if (p.y > _yMax) {
                _yMax = p.y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible using the normal methods of getBounds or getRect as these methods will just return the normal 100x100 square.

I have a few of suggestions for you.

Firstly you could apply the filters dynamically. That way you will have the numbers for the filters and you could do the maths programatically to work out what the actual size is.

You could add a second layer to the movieclip in the fla, which has the dimensions of your original square plus all the filters. Then set the alpha for this square to zero

Thirdly you could just have a png in the fla that contained the square plus, say, the glow within it.

Personally i'd go with the middle option as it would require the least amount of maintenance if the filters or the original square were to change.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I agree about the second suggestion; however, I don't have control over the content/sprite compositions.  Surely, I'm overlooking something.  It's seems it would be quite common to want to identify the sprite dimensions AND the sprite plus filter dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is good news and bad news.  The bad news is that there really isn't an effective way to do this "the right way".  The good news is that there is an adequate way to approximate it.

The general rule is that the size of the width is that it is approximately ( filter.blurX * 1.5 ) + sprite.width where "filter" is the Filter in the sprite.filters array.  The same is true regarding blurY and height.  The other general rule is that the minimum x becomes sprite.x - ( filter.blurX * 1.5 ) / 2;

None of these numbers are "Adobe official", but the work within a reasonable enough margin of error to allow you to create a BitmapData based on that.

Comment: What I presented is the simplest case.  I don't know the internal structure of the SquareContainer instance.  In some cases, it could be a composition of many sprites all with different filters, and some sprites within sprites within filters.  I'm trying to accurately measure just the parent sprite.